# How do I change the definition of a primary key column that's involved in a botched foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql

I forgot to include `AUTO_INCREMENT` when creating a table so I tried to alter it like this

```sql
ALTER TABLE roles CHANGE COLUMN id id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Result:

```
Error Code: 1832. Cannot change column 'role_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'user_role_ibfk_2'
```

Indeed, I tried adding a foreign key constraint into my `user_role` table before, but apparently I did it the wrong way because Workbench tells me there are no foreign keys in `user_role`. `user_role` is a `@JoinTable`

[image]

If I click `Refresh`, I get this error

[image]

```
Unhandled exception: invalid column
constraint_ name for resultset

Check the log for more details
```

The logs I know (the ones in the `AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\database-log` directory) don't have any recent logs

**How do I fix this and provide incrementing for my `role(id)` column while not ruining the tables?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to temporarily disable foreign key checks as a session variable. This is safe to do, since you it won't affect other sessions, and you know you aren't going to do anything to upset the references.

Demo:

```
mysql> create table roles ( id int primary key );

mysql> create table user_role (user_id int, role_id int, primary key (user_id, role_id), foreign key (role_id) references roles(id));
```

I can reproduce the error you got. I checked `modify column` as well just in case that worked, but it didn't.

```
mysql> alter table roles change column id id int not null auto_increment;
ERROR 1833 (HY000): Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'user_role_ibfk_1' of table 'test.user_role'

mysql> alter table roles modify column id  int not null auto_increment;
ERROR 1833 (HY000): Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'user_role_ibfk_1' of table 'test.user_role'
```

Temporarily disabling foreign key checks can allow the action:

```
mysql> set foreign_key_checks=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table roles modify column id  int not null auto_increment;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> set foreign_key_checks=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

And now the table's PK has the AUTO_INCREMENT option as you intended.

```
mysql> show create table roles\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: roles
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Is it safe to turnoff the fks and change the datatype of column from int to smallint unsigned ?

Comment: @SudhirN Safe for what? It certainly won't allow the foreign key to be re-enabled, because int and unsigned are not compatible for references. Also I recall from your other questions you have a database with large numbers of rows. So why are you trying to use smallint, which can only store 2^32 values?

Comment: certain tables in our database will have very limited rows.
for example subjects will never be more thn 100s
likewise topics can be contained within smallint

Existing database used bigint for all the tables pk and fk. I am planning to change it to use smaller types wherever possible.